# linux symlink - move logs from root to a mounted drive

Tags: linux, symlink

My app uses log4j and writes the logs to directory A which is in root directory. I want to move the logs out to a mounted drive without making any change in the application.

Can I use soft symlink to do this? I have created a symlink like this -

```
ln -s A mounted_drive_directory
```

But I still see logs written to directory A.

Comment: That's the wrong direction. You want `A` to be the symlink, so it should be the second argument.

Comment: As a side note: It is bad habit to write to log files directly. Makes log management an admin's nightmare. The proper solution is to use (r)syslog(ng) and logrotate to deal with logs. Let's assume a cluster, for example. What often happens is that the logs are relayed to a central log server, where they are analyzed for problems. With processes writing to a file, this becomes a real nightmare. With syslog, it is rather easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME`, so your arguments order is wrong. You'll have to delete (or move) `A` first before creating the link, or filename conflict will occur.

You could also use mountpoint bindings for that, e.g. `mount --rbind /mounted/drive/directory /full/path/to/A`, but it have to be done on each system boot (or saved in `/etc/fstab` to be auto-executed on boot).

Answer (score 1):

`ln` works a little bit different:

first argument is real folder\file, second - symlink.

```
mv /root/A /root/B; 
ln -s mounted_drive_directory /root/A;
```